# NPE при создании ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

В методе создаётся ImageView, что вызывает java.lang.NullPointerException

```
ImageView shot = new ImageView(this);
```

программирую на java

Comment: приведите полный лог ошибки, пожалуйста. И полностью код класса. Важно, в каком методе жизненного цикла был вызов, что такое `this`

Comment: Если этот код в активити, то сама эта строка не может вызвать NPE, добавьте в вопрос весь связанный с проблемой код, и на какую именно строку в нем указывает компилятор

Comment: метод, в котором происходит ошибка вызывается из onTouch, установленного на другой ImageView Во фрагменте. Сама ошибка в активности

Comment: компилятор указывает, что ошибка происходит именно в этой строке

Comment: @Андрей компилятор указывает? Или во время работы приложения происходит падение? Это вот нихрена не одинаковые ситуации

Comment: при касании ImageView приложение падает, при отладке в дебагере выпадает NPE

Comment: В указанной строке проблемы нет. Она где то в другом месте покажите больше кода

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //some code
            c.createShot();

Comment: с является экземпляром класса активности в которой происходит ошибка

Comment: а Вы, случаем, этот экземпляр не так создаете `c = new Activity()`? Потому что так нельзя!

Comment: private Activity c = new Activity(); А как можно?

Comment: @Андрей экземпляры `Activity` нельзя создавать вручную. Приведите полный код класса, пожалуйста, это будет намного проще, чем длинный список комментов строчить

Comment: вы создали но не добавили в активность, отсюда все проблемы

Comment: @Style-7, а как её добавить?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, Там много ненужных и никак не связанных с проблемой методов

Comment: @Андрей с одной строчкой кода Вам точно никто не поможет

Comment: что именно от кода вам нужно?

Comment: @Андрей куда проще будет, если Вы вставите в вопрос весь код класса, а я потом удалю лишнее.

Comment: нужен код фрагмента?

Comment: да, код фрагмент

Comment: @Андрей Не слушай их, они украдут твой код и продадут Цукербергу! Продолжай писать комменты)

Comment: CreateActivity - это активность, внутри которой находится фрагмент?

Comment: надеюсь, это поможет

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, да

Comment: @Circassian, вряд ли он кому-то нужен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

```
private CreateActivity c = new CreateActivity();
```

Сделайте так:

```
private CreateActivity c;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.c = (CreateActivity) getActivity();
}
```

Пояснение: Вам нужно обратиться к уже существующему экземпляру `CreateActivity`, а не создавать новый. После вызова `onAttach` встроенный во фрагменты метод `getActivity` начинает возвращать текущую активность (именно тот экземпляр, в который вложен фрагмент). Используйте его и приводите тип от `Activity` к `CreateActivity`.

Comment:  
Жаль израсходовал сегодня лимит голосов. Но я обязательно завтра проголосую за этот ответ)

Comment: студия предлагает, чтобы возвращал void

Comment: @Андрей Вы правы, я перепутал возвращаемый тип) У меня-то нет рядом студии с подсказками)

Comment: ну да) Спасибо, всё работает

Comment: @Андрей не удаляйте из вопроса тот код, что сейчас есть, пожалуйста, это может помочь другим узнать свой случай)
И не забудьте отметить ответ, как правильный!
Удачи в разработке)